# i have an Error oop concept in python

Tags: python

```
rows, seats = self._aircraft.seating_plan()
self._seating = [None] + [{letter:None for letter in seats} for _ in rows]
```

and attaching error here

> **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Comment: Please format code a bit

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with OOP, you're simply trying to iterate over a value of `None`.

Comment: BTW, why are you constructing an inhomogeneous list? Instead of making the first item `None` it should be an empty dict to be consistent with the other list items.

Answer (score 1):

You are (trying to) iterate over `seats` and `rows`.  At least one of those is `None`.  You need to find out which, and fix it (or decide what you want to do)

---

Also: your expression:

```
    [None] + [...]
```

Will create a list whose first element is `None`.  Is that really what you 
want?  I'd have thought either

```
    [] + [...]
```

or

```
    [...]
```

or much more likely to be what you want.